# Inline Assembler for Visual Studio Call

Tags: c, visual-studio, inline-assembly

So, first off, this is an assignment for a friend that I'm helping with, and while it's been a while since I've done C, that's not the problem (Or at least I don't think it is), the problem is the assembly code. The assignment must use a function written in inline assembly to sum two numbers that have been passed to the function after having been input by the user, and return the value, which is then output. On running my code, I get errors either reading or writing to memory locations found in the asm function, specifically the second mov command, and the program will hang while attempting to execute that line of code. Tracing the program, one of the values will be stored correctly (Whatever the second value the user enters, which I believe is normal, because values are read in reverse in assembly?) and the other isn't read at all, and the program crashes. I've spent about four hours trying to figure this out, and am now resorting to outside help. Anyways, enough background, trying to be thorough, here's the code. I'm sure what I'm doing is probably something basic and is staring me in the face, but any help is appreciated. Oh, and yes, I made sure masm was enabled in visual studio.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <conio.h>

int sum( int val1, int val2 );
int main (void)
{
int val1=0, val2=0, val3=0;

printf("Hello, this program will add two whole numbers. Please enter the first    number.\n");
scanf("%d",&val1);

printf("Please enter the second number.\n");
scanf("%d",&val2);

val3 = sum(val1, val2);
printf("The sum of %d and %d is %d", val1, val2, val3);
_getch();

return 0;
 }

 int sum ( int val1, int val2 ){
 int val3;

    __asm{  mov eax, val2        ;
            push eax             ;
            mov ebx, val1        ;
            push ebx             ;
            add eax, ebx         ;
            mov ecx, val3        ;
            pop val3             ;
            pop ebx              ;
            pop eax              ;
            pop ecx              ;
            ret                  ;
    }
    return val3;

}
```

Comment: If you `push` twice and `pop` four times, that doesn't look correct. And you can't have both a `ret` and a `return` in the same function.

Comment: http://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/c-and-c/67864-msvc-converting-function-__declspec-naked.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what all the push and pops are for, but this works:

```
int sum ( int val1, int val2 )
{
    int val3;

    __asm{  mov eax, val2        ;
            mov ebx, val1        ;
            add eax, ebx         ;
            mov val3, eax        ;
         }
    return val3;
}
```

Comment: That actually did just fine, mind explaining that? Had something very similar to that, didn't work at all. The push and pops were me trying to be clever after hours of frustration. The original code was actually nearly identical to what you've got, only it wasTrying to learn tho!

Comment: He's leaving the stack management entirely up to the compiler ... compile the code and check the resulting assembler ...

Comment: My original version was nearly identical to that, only val1 was moved in to registry first, instead of val2, apparently that made the difference! Is that because of the order they're passed to the function?

Comment: No, I could have pushed `val1` to `eax` and `val2` to `ebx`. It doesn't really matter in this case. First 2 lines put the values into the registers (eax and ebx respectively). 3rd line adds both registers and puts the result (e.g. the sum) in `eax`. 4th line copies the result from `eax` into `val3`. That's it :)

Comment: Ok well you have several issues .. 1) Why do you push val1 and val2 onto the stack? 2) What exactly are you returning from the function (the return value should be in eax) 3) Why do you have a ret instruction and then a C-style ret?

Comment: TBH though the exampl is far better easier above because the only other option is to declare a naked function and handle the stack frame yourself.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys, I'm definitely gonna start learning more assembly on my own, this has me intrigued, you can do some really cool stuff with it it seems.

Comment: btw big bonus over doing as @Blachshma has done over a naked function is that the compiler won't, AFAIK, inline the resulting code if you use a naked function (though in some circumtances that "might" be a bonus though i find it unlikely)

Comment: Wouldn't it work the same if there was no `val3` at all? I.e. if you'd simply left the sum in `eax`, compiler would have returned that as the function result.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use push and pop when loading CPU registers. The push  instruction causes the value to be written to the memory location pointed to by the SS:[ESP] register pair, where SS is the 16-bit stack segment and ESP is the 32-bit stack pointer. This also decrements ESP by the size of the operand in bytes. The pop instruction performs the inverse operation, reading from the memory location pointed to by SS:[ESP] and incrementing ESP by the size of the operand in bytes.

Comment: In x86 protected mode (the case running under Windows), _SS_ is actually a 16-bit selector (not a segment as you would see in real mode/vm8086 etc) that is used to index into the LGDT or GDT.